# How to apply the PathPatternParser introduced in Spring 5?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I want to create a **GET** request that takes a filepath as a path variable.

As described in the Spring documentation found [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/util/pattern/PathPattern.html), this should be possible by using the following: /resources/{*path}.

I am using Spring Boot 2.1.2 which uses Spring 5.

However when I set up my controller method like this, the request doesn't match the route. An expected matching path would be for example /resources/some/filepath which should lead the PathVariable "path" to be /some/filepath

```java
  @GetMapping("/resources/{*path}")
  public String content(@PathVariable String path) {
    return null;
  }
```

I didn't find any information about any configuration that is needed in order to make use of the new PathPattern. The only other piece of information I found about this new feature is a post at Baeldung (https://www.baeldung.com/spring-5-mvc-url-matching) which doesn't mention anything about configuration. So I expect that it should work out of the box, but it doesn't.

I cloned the project mentioned in the Baeldung post. The corresponding unit tests run. When I copy the Controller method and the unit test to my project, it fails. So I expect that it has to do with configuration.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Hi, could you give us the expecting matching path ?

Comment: Hello, I edited my question and added an example.

Comment: The mapping should work as expected (except that path should be "some/filepath"), are you correctly make a GET request ?

Comment: Yes, when I change the route to "/resources/**", I arrive in the Controller method.

Comment: Not sure that you are looking the correct documentation, please see : 
https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the [Common Application properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/appendix-application-properties.html#common-application-properties-web) in the Spring documentation there's a property called **spring.mvc.pathmatch.matching-strategy**, that's used as "Choice of strategy for matching request paths against registered mappings".

The default value (up to this date) is **ant-path-matcher**, and since you want to use PathPattern, you'll need to write this in the application.properties file:

spring.mvc.pathmatch.matching-strategy=path-pattern-parser

Answer (score 3):

I was finally able to find out the reason for my problem.

Thanks to Fabien's [link](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping).

The AntPathMatcher is the default implementation for the [PathMatcher](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/PathMatcher.html). [1.10.12. Path Matching](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-config-path-matching) shows how to configure the PathMatcher. However the PathMatchConfigurer::setPathMatcher takes a PathMatcher as the argument and AntPathMatcher is the only implementation of PathMatcher so you can not set the [PathPattern](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/util/pattern/PathPattern.html) there...

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configurePathMatch(PathMatchConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer
            .setUseSuffixPatternMatch(true)
            .setUseTrailingSlashMatch(false)
            .setUseRegisteredSuffixPatternMatch(true)
            .setPathMatcher(antPathMatcher())
            .setUrlPathHelper(urlPathHelper())
            .addPathPrefix("/api",
                    HandlerTypePredicate.forAnnotation(RestController.class));
    }

    @Bean
    public UrlPathHelper urlPathHelper() {
        //...
    }

    @Bean
    public PathMatcher antPathMatcher() {
        //...
    }

}
```

The only class where I found the PathPattern in the Baeldung project is the following:

```
@Configuration
public class CorsWebFilterConfig {

    @Bean
    CorsWebFilter corsWebFilter() {
        CorsConfiguration corsConfig = new CorsConfiguration();
        corsConfig.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("http://allowed-origin.com"));
        corsConfig.setMaxAge(8000L);
        corsConfig.addAllowedMethod("PUT");
        corsConfig.addAllowedHeader("Baeldung-Allowed");

        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource(new PathPatternParser());
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", corsConfig);

        return new CorsWebFilter(source);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Enmanuel Rodríguez Paz gave a [good declarative solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66339822/).

You can also configure Spring 5.3 to use `PathPatternParser` imperatively like so :

```java
package com.stackoverflow.users.pyb.questions.55457184;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.PathMatchConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.util.pattern.PathPatternParser;

public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

  @Override
  public void configurePathMatch(PathMatchConfigurer configurer) {
    configurer
        .setPatternParser(new PathPatternParser());
  }
}
```