# URI pattern matching in Spring Boot 2.1

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, url-routing

With introduction of 5th version, Spring has changed the default URL pattern matching mechanism from [AntPathMatcher](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/AntPathMatcher.html) to [PathPattern](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.0.0.RC3_to_5.0.0.RC4/Spring%20Framework%205.0.0.RC4/org/springframework/web/util/pattern/PathPattern.html) class. Spring Boot 2.1, which is based on Spring 5.1 version, does not follow this chage, as `AntPathMatcher`  it still used for the processing:

```
@GetMapping("/spring5/{*id}") //PathPattern implementation, compilation error
@GetMapping("/spring5/**") // AntPathMatcher implementation, works fine
```

Is there a way to enable `PathPattern` matching mechanisms for Spring Boot 2.1 applications?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to apply the PathPatternParser introduced in Spring 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55457184/how-to-apply-the-pathpatternparser-introduced-in-spring-5)

Comment: And also please look at https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping this might be useful

Answer (score 0):

Ant Matcher will work with 
`/spring5/**`
and normal path pattern will work with

```
@GetMapping("/spring5/{*id}")
public void methodName(@PathVariable String id)
```

try and add @PathVariable as well and it will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Spring mvc, and i found out this solution for Spring mvc:

In your webApplicationcontext configuration file, override the "configurePathMatch" method as follows:

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurationSupport {

@Override
public void configurePathMatch(PathMatchConfigurer configurer) {
configurer.setPatternParser(new PathPatternParser());
}
```

As Spring mvc official document states:

"***setPatternParser(PathPatternParser patternParser)**: Enable use of parsed PathPatterns as described in AbstractHandlerMapping.setPatternParser(PathPatternParser).*"

Hope this will help you somehow!